# How do I close the input if submit is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend, web-deployment

So I've got a submit button with a class of search, when clicked and the value of the input with a class of searchBar is empty then searchBar display:block and doesn't submit the form. However i want to be able to close searchBar if the value is still empty but the submit (search) is clicked again.

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
if ($.trim($(".searchBar").val()) === "") {
    $('.searchBar').css('display', 'block');
    return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
});
```

HTML:

```
 <form id="form" action="">
  <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Product name or ID" name="search" class="searchBar" />
  <input type="submit" readonly="readonly" class="search" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
  #form .searchBar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you provided enough information for someone to be able to help you. A demo complete with html would help a lot.

Comment: @Moritur added html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of question is correct, You can toggle the display of the searchbox to achieve what you need

```
 $('.searchBar').css('display', 'block'); // instead of this


 $('.searchBar').toggle(); // put this
```

Comment: Helpful Answer . .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code i have done something like this

```js
$('#form').submit(function() {
                if ($.trim($(".searchBar").val()) === "") {
                    $('.searchBar').show();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

```css
#form #search {
                display: none;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
            <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Product name or ID" name="search" id="search" value="testValue" class="searchBar" />
            <input type="submit" readonly="readonly" class="search" />
        </form>
```

You can check this example if you like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>        
        <style>
            #form #search {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" action="" method="post">
            <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Product name or ID" name="search" id="search" value="testValue" class="searchBar" />
            <input type="submit" readonly="readonly" class="search" />
        </form>
        <script>

            $('#form').submit(function() {
                if ($.trim($(".searchBar").val()) === "") {
                    $('.searchBar').show();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand right you can try this piece of code:

```
var countClick=0;
$('#form').submit(function() {
    countClick++;
    if ($.trim($(".searchBar").val()) === "") 
    {    
        if(countClick==1)
        {
            $('.searchBar').css('display', 'block');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('.searchBar').css('display', 'none');
            return false;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```